# Hide Finder window when mounting DMG via objective c code

Tags: objective-c, macos

I am trying to mount a Read only DMG file via code.

```
    NSArray *args = [ NSArray arrayWithObjects : @"mount", dmgPath, nil ] ;
    [ mountDMGTask setLaunchPath : @"/usr/bin/hdiutil" ] ;
    [ mountDMGTask setArguments : args ] ;
    [ mountDMGTask launch ] ;
    [ mountDMGTask waitUntilExit ] ;
    int result = [ mountDMGTask terminationStatus ] ;
```

This mounts the DMG just fine. But it also opens a finder window with the contents of the mounted volume. I don't want this to happen as I copy the contents of the volume via code.